# How to get the last n digits of a hexadecimal number?

Tags: c++, hex, modulo

I need a really short way to extract the last 4 digits of a hex number. So an input of `0x2479c` should throw an output of `0x479c`. I want to avoid converting and reconverting to binary.

Modulo division, which would generally work for decimal numbers, does not work in this case.

```
0x2479c  modulo 0xffff = 0x479e
```

which isn't correct. I'm trying to achieve this is c/c++.

Comment: if you do modulo with decimal numbers, you don't divide by 9, do you? `0x2479c mod 0x10000 = 0x479c`.

Comment: Looks like you mixed up you bitwise 'and' and your modulo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about elementary-school maths.

Comment: Replace `%` with `&`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, since when is *bitwise and* about elementary-school maths?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi there's no bitwise and in the question.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, there is in comments, and would be in answers. Seriously, this is about programming. It may be poor and not well-researched, but it doesn't strike me as *off-topic*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Seriously, you don't even need to mention bitwise and anywhere in order to answer this correctly. Taking the remainder with `0x10000` works just as well as AND-ing with `0xffff`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, I'm afraid hexadecimal is still not taught in elementary school either.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a mask and then a byte wise 'and' with an other value. In your case :

```
0x2479c & 0x0ffff
```

Comment: `s/should/could/g`. Modulo division by `0x10000` works equally well.

Answer (score 3):

Either use a mask

```
0x2479c & 0x0ffff
```

or the modulo operator

```
0x2479c % (0x10000);
```

You were off by one in the operand of modulo.